# need guidance using genetic algorithm tool in matlab with function using multiple parameters

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I need some guidance on using ga function in matlab. All example I found were dealing with one variable (parameter) eg.

```
 function y = two_min(x)
 if x<=20
     y = x+1; 
 else
     y = x+1;
 end
```

so i can just call ga(@two_min,1) to start.

but when I try to do it with multiple variables eg.

```
 function y = two_min(x,z)
 if x<=20
     y = x+1+z;
 else
     y = x+1+z;
 end
```

it keeps showing me error: not enough input aruguments..
isn't it because I didn't set constraints or other options?
in what format should I set the other option..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it executes your function two_min, it'll pass in the value for x, and z won't have been defined anywhere prior to its use, hence your error. One thing you could try is binding your z-value prior to your call to ga:

```
a = 500; %the value that will be used for z
fitness_fun = @(x) two_min(x,a);
n_var = 1;
[x,fval] = ga(fitness_fun,n_var)
```

Note that this will just take the value of a at the point of fitness_fun's creation as the value for z, so if you change the value of "a" again later, it won't have any effect on the value of z in two_min unless you re-create the anonymous function (this is because matlab anonymous functions are closures, and their internal state is taken from the workspace upon its creation).

This is one way to do what you were asking about; did you have something else in mind?

Comment: it didn't solve my problem, but you actually gave me a hint, i used vector instead and it works!.eg y = two_min(x)  x(1) and x(2) are two variables